# Transceiver for TDoA measurements

Tags: estimation, bandwidth, radar, radio, time-of-arrival

Could someone advise me on some module for making the TDoA position system for my research work? I need to have measurements with an accuracy of a few meters. It equals a bandwidth of about 20 MHz. I guess there are some modules of 2.4 GHz with such bandwidth and given propagation time and also raw output without any high-level stacks like OSI. The only output of the threshold device after the matched filter maybe. I also need it to have a possibility to set my own partial signal (for example I want to use M-code).

Comment: I don't really think asking for hardware recommendations really works great here, to be honest. Not really a signal processing question! But: what you describe is a software defined radar, which means you'll probably have to implement that using software defined radio, so check out [gr-radar](https://github.com/kit-cel/gr-radar/tree/maint-3.8); nothing stopping you from extending it to use *your* waveform. In fact, people already did similar things. Extending it to be a bistatic TDoA radar is pretty simple. I've advised a student's MSc thesis on TDoA location, too, no great code, but it's

Comment: really just  buying an SDR device with two or more receive chains, and then writing a correlator, to get a start. Then you start getting smarter with interpolation, averaging, tracking, error estimation, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Marcus Müller. But could you clear up how can I embody the TDoA navigation? Use transmitter on the board (quadrotor) and receive its signal in place of beacons? Is it the TDoA method backward?

Comment: I can't tell you how to build your system. Navigation is waaaaaaay more than just TDoA; this feels like you need to first plan your system and its purpose, before considering what to buy as components.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I only need to obtain two estimations of the time difference of arrival at every moment. It's supposed to use the simplest schema to extract the information from the signals. There is no need to use a large number of symbols, but I want to use at least two different signals in order to transmit something like ephemeris. Maybe it also be redundant and I would agree to use only two TDoA measurements. But I don't want to deal with oscillators and synchronization and other things. Because I focused on control theory.

Comment: My colleagues suggested to me their board with a bandwidth of 7.5 MHz, but it produces too low accuracy. Probably, it would be better to use acoustic signals to obtain high accuracy measurements

Comment: Um, honestly, if you're not even sure you're doing radio or acoustic localization, this might all be a bit too early to discuss hardware. Also, where do these 7.5 MHz bandwidth come from? That's very little, indeed; affordable modern SDR does a multiple of that, easily, so if you don't like that bandwidth, don't use it, but use a larger one? But, citing you, "for a few meters" of accuracy, indeed, 7.5 MHz is enough.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, It's doesn't matter what to use. It's only a one-time experiment in order to improve my research work (modeling). Now then I need to obtain two TDoA measurements for the space case and produce an optimal control law. I could use quadrotors in a real experiment. But I need to confirm a possibility to transmit the ephemeris and give the navigational information for guidance during a short period of time.

Comment: My model works well but some people doubt that I could get highly accurate navigation (using an accumulation of coarse) and decoding at least one ephemeris (but two are better) at any time. I am afraid the 7.5 bandwidth will require a large period of time for accumulation to get high accuracy. But I also don't sure about using an acoustic signal for the reason of its possible perturbations due to the quadrotor propellers which require more time to find a solution.

Comment: And It's supposing a short period of time because this is a very short-range system for many users. Of course, I want to demonstrate only with one receiver (user). So I need only to prove my algorithms without deep signal processing.